# Problema consulta a tabla autoreferenciada

Tags: sql-server, menú

Quiero poder armar mi menú dinámico con la siguiente estructura de datos:[image: tablas de menú]

el menú está restringido por roles de usuario.
A mi tabla menú, le he añadido una columna id_menu_padre para poder armar la estructura tipo "árbol" que debe tener mi menú.

El problema que tengo es que no encuentro la manera de hacer mi query para que me muestre los resultados que obtengo incluyendo el que se encuentra en verde:

```
      $roles_menu =  collect(DB::select("
                                    select m.id_menu as menu_id,
                                    m.des_menu as menu_des,
                                    m.url_menu as url, 
                                    m.id_menu_padre as id_menu_padre, 
                                    (select des_menu from menu where menu.id_menu = m.id_menu_padre) as des_menu_padre 

                                   from menu m
                                   left join menu me on m.id_menu = me.id_menu_padre  
                                       join rol_menu on rol_menu.id_menu = m.id_menu 
                                       join roles on rol_menu.id_rol = roles.id_role AND 
                                           roles.id_role = $id_rol"))->toArray();

    return $roles_menu;
```

[image: resultado deseado]

(Actualizo)

La única manera que he encontrado para obtener los resultados que necesito es la siguiente:

```
WITH MenuCTE AS
( 
SELECT H.id_menu AS id_menu, H.des_menu AS des_menu, H.url_menu AS url_menu, 
id_menu_padre 
FROM menu H, rol_menu RM, roles R
WHERE RM.id_menu = H.id_menu AND RM.id_rol = R.id_role AND R.id_role = 23 
UNION ALL
SELECT P.id_menu, P.des_menu, P.url_menu, P.id_menu_padre 
FROM menu P, rol_menu RM, roles R
INNER JOIN MenuCTE s ON id_menu = s.id_menu_padre 
UNION ALL
SELECT P.id_menu, P.des_menu, P.url_menu, P.id_menu_padre 
FROM menu P 
 JOIN MenuCTE s ON P.id_menu = s.id_menu_padre 
) 
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MenuCTE
```

Sin embargo, el hecho de tener que usar "distinct" me indica que seguramente hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MenuCTE
```

Comment: adjunta el código donde tienes problemas, pero no imagen, puedes dejar la imagen del resultado pero agrega código

Comment: Ok. Ya lo edité

Answer (score 0):

De momento, ten en cuenta que con

```
UNION ALL
```

Le estás pidiendo que te muestre las líneas en común incluyendo duplicados.
Prueba a cambiar la clausula por

```
UNION
```

y no te debería sacar duplicados.
En cualquier caso, entiendo que las tablas donde guardas las entradas de menús contendrán unas decenas, como mucho cientos de registros. No vale la pena optimizar esas consultas, hay que centrarse en las tablas que contienen muchos más registros.